# CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: cuda

I got the message:

> "cutilCheckMsg() CUTIL CUDA error :
>   kernel launch failure : CUDA driver
>   version is insufficient for CUDA
>   runtime version."

While trying to run an example source code. Also happens for the function `cutilSafeCall`.

I am using:

- Windows 7 64bits
- Visual studio 2008
- CUDA developer driver, toolkit, and SDK 3.1
- Emulation mode

Comment: It sounds like you need to update your driver. And you might want to mention what OS you are using, what CUDA SDK version, etc.

Comment: Had the same message...in my case it had been just after a windows update, and the process removed Cuda Toolkit...simply required reinstallation.  Check version compatibility.  Here's my known working config:  Windows 10, 64 bit, cuda toolkit v9.0, Visual Studio 2015, Nvidia Quadro P4000, Python version and libraries:  Python 3.6.7, Tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1, Cudatoolkit 9.0, cudnn 7.1.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I saw the same at runtime with the latest driver on Mac OS 10.6.

```
cudaError_t error = cudaGetDevice(&device);
printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
```

I went back to the developer site, downloaded the driver again and now it runs.
http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_1_downloads.html#MacOS

Answer (score 24):

You need to ensure that your driver version matches or exceeds your CUDA Toolkit version.

For 2.3 you need a 190.x driver, for 3.0 you need 195.x and for 3.1 you need 256.x (actually anything up to the next multiple of five is ok, e.g. 258.x for 3.1).

You can check your driver version by either running the deviceQueryDrv SDK sample or go into the NVIDIA Control Panel and choose System Information.

Download an updated driver from [www.nvidia.com/drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/drivers).

Answer (score 8):

Counterintuitively, this error also happens if `libcuda.so` is not found, even when versions reported by `nvidia-smi` match perfectly. This library is part of nvidia-drivers package (On CentOS: `nvidia-driver-latest-cuda-libs`, on Gentoo `x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers`). It is possible to have the CUDA Tookit with `nvcc` and `libcudart` installed and building your app fine, but the drivers part not installed, causing this error.

To diagnose whether this is the reason, use `strace`:

```
strace -f -e trace=file ./your_cuda_app
```

and check for open calls to `libcuda.so*`, at least one of them should return with a success code, like so:

```
4928  open("/lib64/libcuda.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Comment: In my case, I'm using docker image for a service, and I forgot to add ` --runtime=nvidia` in my docker run, which caused `libcuda.so` to be unavailable.

Answer (score 5):

You can either download the latest driver OR use an older toolkit version to compile your code.

Comment: You also need to make sure that your include / library directories point to the correct version. I have CUDA 5.5 and CUDA 6.0, and even when I changed the build settings to use the 5.5 compiler (in VS project settings), it was still quietly linking to 6.0 libraries (in VS Options / C++ Directories). Now it's working perfectly. Silly me ...

Answer (score 4):

My cent,

with Linux/Unix this error **may be related to the selected GPU mode (Performance/Power Saving Mode)**, when you select (with nvidia-settings utiliy) the integrated Intel GPU and you execute the deviceQuery script... you get this error:

-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

**But this error is misleading**, by selecting back the NVIDIA(Performance mode) with nvidia-settings utility the problem disappears.

**It is not a version problem**.

Regards

P.s: "Power Saving Mode" tells `Optimus` to activate the CPU integrated Intel GPU

Answer (score 3):

CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version: means your GPU can`t been manipulated by the CUDA runtime API, so you need to update your driver.

Comment: just download the latest version and install

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to run my docker container with `nvidia-docker run ...` instead of `docker run ...`

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem, updated my graphic driver but the problem still remained. I finally decided to remove Cuda 9.2 and install Cuda 8, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me :

1. Installing `TensorFlow version 1.14`, installing `keras`
2. Install `CUDA 10.0` from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exenetwork for windows
3. Download the compatible `CuDNN i.e 7.4.2`
   from https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive
4. set the following in the path variable
   `cudnn-10.0-windows10-x64-v7.4.2.24\cuda\bin`
   `cudnn-10.0-windows10-x64-v7.4.2.24\cuda\include`
   `cudnn-10.0-windows10-x64-v7.4.2.24\cuda\lib\x64`
5. Restart the Pc

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be because of incorrect environment setup, e.g. Docker image setup. Although the driver itself is correct, sufficient for your program. If your LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the wrong driver, it can throw this error. In my case, i get this error when using /usr/local/nvidia/lib/libcuda.so, and if I use /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libcuda.so everything goes right.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is related to the TBB lib:
[Error OpenCV with CUDA using TBB for multiple GPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295350/error-opencv-with-cuda-using-tbb-for-multiple-gpus)

Try rebuilding it making sure you passed the following parameters to CMake (assuming you already installed "tbb" and "tbb-devel" packages:

```
-D WITH_TBB=YES -D TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/tbb
```