# Error OpenCV with CUDA using TBB for multiple GPUs

Tags: multithreading, opencv, cuda, tbb

My OpenCV CUDA program runs fine using a single NVidia 580GTX, but when using another, it gives the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (invalid device ordinal) in mallocPitch

I know I need TBB to assign a GPU its job, but even though I installed OpenCV with TBB support (followed the willowgarage website), it says **TBB support is required (CMake key 'WITH_TBB' must be true**). Any help would really be appreciated since I need this to complete my computer science Master's project.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux? If Linux, do you have `libtbb` and `libtbb-dev` installed?

Comment: its linux and yes its installed. cmake wouldn't compile if TBB wasn't installed. is there perhaps a flag that i need to compile it with? eg. for cuda in opencv its -lopencv

Comment: TBB is unaware of OpenCV, no special flags are necessary.

Comment: oh i see. i just find it weird that it says: TBB support is required (CMake key 'WITH_TBB' must be true).

But when i build opencv you can clearly see its on: cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D CUDA_NPP_LIBRARY_ROOT_DIR:STRING=/home/ddduke/SDK/ -D WITH_CUDA:BOOL=ON -D WITH_TBB=YES -D TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/tbb ..

Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                    NO
--     Use TBB:                    YES
--     Use Cuda:                   YES
--     Use Eigen:                  NO

Comment: Can you make sure your other cuda programs work ? do you have read / write permissions to /dev/nvidia* (do they even exist ?)

Comment: none of my cuda programs work when i have two graphics cards installed. when i have one it works fine. i need to use tbb to specify which gpu to run it on i think, but tbb doesn't want to pick up the second card (maybe). so far it is just speculation so tomorrow i am going to install a other opencv version. perhaps its a bug in build 7232 (i'm using development builds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok its solved. turns out it was build 7232 that was the problem, since it works with the latest opencv build(7292) with no problems. Thanks all for the support