# CUDA version is insufficient for CUDART version. running in emu mode without NVIDIA card

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I get the error -

```
cutilCheckMsg() CUTIL CUDA error : Kernel execution failed
: CUDA version is insufficient for CUDART version.
```

when I run the sample code. The code however builds successfully

Details of the environment Im running the program -

Windows XP with NO NVIDIA driver

Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition

Cuda toolkit, sdk 3.0

Emulation mode

Here is a similar question asked on SO before but in that case the person had NVIDIA card. I do not have NVIDIA card on my machine. - [CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253257/cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-runtime-version)

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to run CUDA code without a GPU is to use [CUDA x86 from PGI](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cuda-x86.htm).  Emulation mode was dropped from CUDA several versions ago (current version is CUDA 4.2).

Comment: He did say he was using CUDA 3.0, which still had emulation support AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, but it was mostly useless and I want to emphasize (in case it was not obvious from my answer) that it is not supported.