# UBUNTU 16.04 CUDA 10.0: CUDA version not supporting latest nvidia drivers

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I am currently downloading Caffe. While attempting. While executing  "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 make runtest ", I get

> F0924 21:13:04.768816 13249 syncedmem.hpp:22] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0)  CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat common problem when getting started with a ML library. You really have to make sure that your versions of CUDA, cuDNN, and the graphics driver are all compatible with one another.

While this post is somewhat dated, it does provide steps for resolving the problem:
[What can I do against 'CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669258/what-can-i-do-against-cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-runtime-vers?rq=1)

See here for more debugging steps as well: [CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253257/cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-runtime-version?rq=1)